# Resharper shortcut for closing Find Usages window?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, resharper

What's the Resharper shortcut for closing Find Usages or similar type of window?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> will close most recently used tab in any ReSharper toolwindow. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> will close the toolwindow. <kbd>Esc</kbd> inside toolwindow will focus code editor.

Answer (score 2):

I use Ctrl+F4.

Shift + Esc doesn't work for me even though  "Options... Keyboard" "Window.CloseWindow" shows Shift + Esc. (VS 2013, R# 8.2)

Answer (score 1):

Find Usages is a Tool Window like any other, so the shortcut to close it is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (or, if this doesn't appear to work, check what it says in VS `Tools | Options...`, `Keyboard`, `Window.CloseToolWindow`).

THAT SAID I've always been slightly hazy on how to use the keyboard to get **focus** to / from Tool Windows - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> works fine from a code window *into* a Tool Window, but doesn't always seem to work to get you out...

Comment: Thank you for Ctrl+Tab shortcut

Comment: Getting focus to a specific tool window is something I do with the specific keys for the specific window - for the Resharper Find Results tool window, thats ctrl+alt+F12.  Then crtl_esc works great.  Additionally, if you have all your tool Windows as auto-hide, it doesn't really matter which one you open with a keyboard combination - get focus to any and crtl-esc will get rid of all of it.